# get parent category of current category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a website where my clients want me to display the parent category of current category. I know how to display the category of current product.

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
```

But I'm struggling to get the parent category of that category. Please help me regarding this. I'm a budding developer.

Answer (score 1):

To get Parent Category Id you must know the current category Id, for that you need to write

```
<?php
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$curent_cat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();
$curent_cat_id = $curent_cat->getId();?>
```

Now you can get Parent Category Id.
write the code given below to get the Id

```
<?php $parentId=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($curent_cat_id)->getParentId();
echo $parentId; // $parentId will print your current category's parent Id
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento.html) blog it contains the necessary information to achieve your requirement

Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this short code to get the parent category:

```
$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();
$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
exit($parent->getName());
```